# Transfer an App Store app to another machine without internet access

Tags: install, mac-appstore

I have a Mac, running Mountain Lion, which does not have internet access and cannot be given internet access. I would like to take an app, which is only available on the App Store, and install it on this Mac. I do have another Mac with internet access and can purchase the App on it. However, when I try to copy and install the app on the other machine, the app won't launch.

How can I accomplish this?

I have no intention of using the App on the Machine on which the purchase was made.

Comment: Can’t you just give the Mac internet access for a while? If you can, you only need to authorise it once. The app will run on it after that.

Comment: No, I cannot. Wish I could.

Comment: Then your only solution is getting the app from “other sources” or cracking the code-sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short of cracking the code signing, you will need to have the receiving Mac connect to Apple's servers (through the internet) at least once to validate your account on that Mac. Once that is done, you should be able to run apps for the length of time that the code signing certificate remains valid.

You could also see about contacting the developer and see if you can purchase the app from them directly if you don't want to have the App Store model for software installation and validation.